# git clone command not working for https URL. For ssh it works - Ubuntu 20 Git version 2.25.1

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

I am facing this strange issue of not being able to clone any GIT repository from github.com over HTTPS URLs. However, I can clone using the SSH method. This is done on Ubuntu 20 and Git version 2.25.1.
e.g. below clone command with HTTPS URL will wait and then show a timeout message as below

```
$$ git clone --progress --verbose https://github.com/findmrkhan/decision-tree-model-card-fraud.git
Cloning into 'cnn'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/findmrkhan/decision-tree-model-card-fraud.git/': Operation timed out after 300008 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

However, the below SSH method works fine for the same repository

```
$$git clone git@github.com:findmrkhan/decision-tree-model-card-fraud.git
Cloning into 'decision-tree-model-card-fraud'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 64, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (64/64), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
remote: Total 64 (delta 33), reused 27 (delta 9), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (64/64), 388.17 KiB | 328.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (33/33), done.
```

I have tested for network connectivity. telnet and wget commands are able to connect to github.com without issues

```
$$ nc -v github.com 443
Connection to github.com 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!

$$ wget https://github.com/findmrkhan/decision-tree-model-card-fraud.git
--2020-12-23 01:46:18--  https://github.com/findmrkhan/decision-tree-model-card-fraud.git
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 13.234.176.102
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|13.234.176.102|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://github.com/findmrkhan/decision-tree-model-card-fraud [following]
--2020-12-23 01:46:19--  https://github.com/findmrkhan/decision-tree-model-card-fraud
Reusing existing connection to github.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘decision-tree-model-card-fraud.git’

decision-tree-model-card-fraud.git              [ <=>                                                                                        ] 130.53K  --.-KB/s    in 0.1s    

2020-12-23 01:46:19 (1.14 MB/s) - ‘decision-tree-model-card-fraud.git’ saved [133658]
```

I have installed and uninstall git multiple times but still the same issue occurs.
Also, I have used other git clients like Git Cola. It works fine for https URLs.

Any clue or configuration setting that can fix this issue will help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just said `git clone https://github.com/findmrkhan/decision-tree-model-card-fraud.git` into the Terminal on my Mac and it worked fine.

Comment: Are you behind firewall and/or proxy?

Comment: matt, thanks for replying. I am on my home network and there is no firewall. To check the network, as I mentioned, I did a telnet test (`nc -v github.com 443`) and also a (`wget https://github.com/findmrkhan/decision-tree-model-card-fraud.git`) on my repo. Both worked fine which means that network connectivity is not an issue.

Comment: One possibility I am suspecting is that github.com is not allowing me to clone on https i.e. they have blacklisted my IP. How can I confirm if this is the case and how can I resolve that ?